# Rails ActiveStorage Updating attached file after processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Fairly new to using ActiveStorage (love it so far!), but I am running into an issue with trying to figure out how to update a previously attached item.

I have a front-end form that allows a user to upload a PDF, my backend then takes the PDF and scrapes it for data, then exports the data to an excel spreadsheet. My code (when I call to re-attach the export), I see my item in my specified s3 bucket, but its a hashed key name.

```
class Export < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :item

  def process_pdf!
    pdf_file_name = "#{item.blob.key}_#{item.blob.filename.to_s}"
    xls_file_name = "#{item.blob.key}_#{item.blob.filename.to_s.sub('pdf', '')}"
    file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{pdf_file_name}"
    File.open(file, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(pdf.download)
    end

    PdfScraper.call(pdf_file: file, output_name: xls_file_name)
    self.item.attach(
      io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{xls_file_name}"),
      filename: "#{xls_file_name}.xlsx",
      content_type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    )
    File.delete(file)
    true
  end
end
```

How do I attach the generated excel spreadsheet?

Comment: ` io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{xls_file_name}"),` - `xls_file_name` variable just holds the file name, not with extension?

Comment: I ended up changing a bit of the code. I am going to paste my solution soon